If $J$ is a two-sided ideal of $k$-algebra $A\otimes_k B$, then $I=J\cap B$ is a two-sided ideal of $B$.
Let $A$ and $B$ be finite dimensional $k$-algebra, where $k$ is a field.
If $J$ is an two sided ideal of $k$-algebra $A\otimes_k B$, consider $I=J\cap B$, I stuck with proving that I is an two sided ideal of $B$.
I'm confused on what exactly $I=J\cap B$ looks like, or maybe we can prove it without knowing its form?
In this condition, Is that $A\otimes_k I\subset J$?
Thanks for your help!

I assume that by $J \cap B$, you mean the preimage of $J$ under the ring homomorphism $B \to A \otimes_{k} B$ sending $b \in B$ to $1 \otimes b$. (If not, what else could you mean?) In that case, you can use (or prove, if this result is unfamiliar) that the preimage of any two-sided ideal under a ring homomorphism is itself a two-sided ideal.

That my question, I not sure what $J\cap B$ means. But I think you are correct.

@ Alex Wertheim By your definition, Is $A\otimes_k I\subset J$?
